# Общение между основным и дочерним процессом

Tags: c++, c++-cli

Делаю интерфейс на C++CLI отдельно от основной логики, которая написана на C++ и является консольным приложением. 
Запускаю из CLI с помощью

```
Process^ proc = gcnew Process();
proc->StartInfo->RedirectStandardInput = true;
proc->StartInfo->UseShellExecute = false;
proc->StartInfo->FileName = "c.exe";
proc->Start();
```

А теперь вопрос: а что дальше-то? Как мне организовать общение между ними? 
Когда я нажимаю на кнопку, что мне нужно сделать, что бы отправить запрос в дочерний процесс, как его там обработать, и наоборот?

Comment: Почему не делать интерфейс сразу на C++? Какое взаимодействие должно быть реализовано? Какую задачу решает консольное приложение?

Comment: @GreenDragon нехочунебуду писать на WinAPI. Других причин нет. Взаимодействие типа "юзер нажал кнопку - передать в дочерний процесс текст из textBox", или "нажал кнопку - запросить результат" и т.п.

Comment: Тогда лучше воспользуйтесь библиотекой\фреймворком для C++ или пишите сразу на C#, если очень хотите .Net. Если информация должна передаваться во время выполнения - используйте сокеты, если только во время запуска - хватит и аргументов командной строки.

Comment: Я думаю, вам нужно сделать библиотеку (dll) с логикой на С++, а не отдельное приложение (процесс). Далее просто подключаете эту либу к приложению на C++/CLI.

Comment: Cмотрите [Межпроцессное взаимодействие](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Межпроцессное_взаимодействие) - там перечислено множество способов. В общем, гуглите Inter Process Communication - IPC.

Answer (score 0):

не сишник. просто размышления.
**предполагаю** есть два пути, подхода

1. общаться с  post get
2. использовать буфер/разделяемую память/ещё как там оно может называться

я бы гуглил так [C++ subprocess shared buffer](https://www.google.ru/search?q=C%2B%2B+subprocess%20shared%20buffer&lr=lang_ru)

[Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms686958(v=vs.85).aspx)

[Sub-processing with modern C++](http://templated-thoughts.blogspot.ru/2016/03/sub-processing-with-modern-c.html)

[Sharing data between Processes in Windows: Named Pipe and Shared Memory](https://www.spiria.com/en/blog/desktop-software/sharing-data-between-processes-windows-named-pipe-and-shared-memory)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74042/discussion-on-answer-by-qwabra------).